# inverse of uniformly continuous function is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

```
Inverse of uniformly continuous function is uniformly continuous?
```

Assume that $ X,Y$ are  metric spaces and let  $f:X\to Y$ such that $f$ is bijective and uniformly continuous. Then can we predict that $f^{-1}$  is uniformly continuous? Suppose not, what condition I should add to make $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Perhaps if $Y$ is compact...

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt x $ comes to mind.

Comment: Without further assumptions on $X,Y$ or $f$, Then $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily U.C.

Comment: mmm..if Y is compact its trivial..know@ajotatxe but i am expecting somewhat less condition..

Comment: @ajotatxe No. It should be $X$ rather than $Y$ being compact. We can't conclude $f^{-1}$ is continuous even with $Y$ being compact. Example: $[0,1)\ni t\mapsto e^{i2\pi t}\in S^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider $f:\Bbb R\to(-1,1)$ with
$$f(x)=\frac1\pi\tan^{-1}(x)$$

Comment: kindly prove this..@ajotatxe

Comment: @gloom: $\tan x$ is unbounded with an unbounded derivative over $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, hence it cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: To show uniform continuity of $f$ is pretty straightforward, but long. Basic idea to control $\epsilon$ is taking a compact somewhere and then use that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)$ exists. The *not* uniform continuity of $f^{-1}$ follows from vertical asymptotes at $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: is it bijective??@JackD'Aurizio and he used only $\tan ^{-1}x$ know??

Comment: Uniform continuity of $f$ is simple: It has bounded derivative, hence is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 3):

An extreme yet valid example: let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, then the map $\Bbb N\ni n\mapsto q_n\in\Bbb Q$, both sides equipped with the Euclidean metric, is bijective and UC, but its inverse is *nowhere* continuous.